# AJAX validation form in custom backend module

Tags: module, magento-1, javascript, forms, backend

I create custom module and would like to validate the input fields such date.

I tried in Form.php

```
public function _prepareForm()
{        
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'     => 'edit_form',
        'method' => 'post'
    ));

    $f = $form->addFieldset('User', array(
        'legend' => 'Add User',
        'class'  => 'fieldset-wide'
    ));

    $f->addField('to', 'date', array(
        'name'     => 'to',
        'label'    => 'Date to',
        'format'   => 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        'class'    => 'validate-date',
        'required' => true
    ));
}
```

But the class is not added, and nothing does it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Now i have answer, but not have a privileges to answer my question.
Ok, this is working code:
`code`
$f->addField('from', 'date', array(
            'label'              => 'From',
            'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
            'image'              => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format'             => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
            'class'              => 'validate-date'

        ));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is my working code:

```
public function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'     => 'edit_form',
        'method' => 'post'
    ));

    $f = $form->addFieldset('User', array(
        'legend' => 'Add User',
        'class'  => 'fieldset-wide'
    ));

    $f->addField('from', 'date', array(
        'label' => 'From',
        'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
        'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
        'class' => 'validate-date')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `validate_class`, not `class`

```
$f->addField('to', 'date', array(
    'name'     => 'to',
    'label'    => 'Date to',
    'format'   => 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    'validate_class'    => 'validate-date',
    'required' => true
));
```

look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Related` as an example.

Comment: waw.
If extends from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form it's only "class" if extends from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid it's "validate_class".
Thank you for directions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm not sure what you question is exactly about.
I guess you are trying to assign the class **validate-date** to your date "to" field?

My suggestion to test and/or solve your problem: Try adding just a plain text-field and add validation to the form. Does this work?